# get column number of second match of a string in a header row in XL

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to return the column number of the second (or even nth) match of a header text string. For example lets say I have a sheet with the strings "Tom", Dick", "Harry"  and "Tom" again in cells A1 - D1. How do I search for the string "Tom" in the header and return the column number (4) of the second occurrence of the string "Tom"

I have tried various combos of index, sumproduct, SMALL and match but all the answers I'v seen so far seem to assume that you're searching for data down rows rather across a single header row.

I'm using excel 2016.

Comment: You say `in cells A1 - A4` but then state that you want to search in a single row.  What you've stated conflicts with that.  Do you mean `in cells A1 - D1` where the values are all in row 1 (instead of the values all being in column A)?

Comment: Question amended to reflect Tiger's comment, yes I did mean cells A1 to D1

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you:

```
=SMALL(INDEX((A1:D1="Tom")*COLUMN(A1:D1),),COUNTIF(A1:D1,"<>Tom")+2)
```

You can replace "Tom" with a cell reference (like A2 which would contain "Tom"), and the last number at the end (The 2 in `+2`) is the instance found you're looking for.

Comment: Great, thank you tiger, that worked a treat, and yes I did mean A1 - D1 . Q amended :-)